# OS X Excel 2011 VBA Save File Name

Tags: macos, vba, excel, excel-2011

I need to write a script to save a worksheet with to a predetermined location and the save name is filled from values within the worksheet.  I can get it to save in the proper location, but the file name returns a combination of FATPMetiFolderPath and FATPMetiPath (\Volumes\MFS1\Groups\METI...\METIman\MMP0123 - FATP.xlsm).  I can do this just fine with Windows Excel VBA, but I have never used a Mac before.  I am programming on a PC, but it needs to be able to be saved properly if used on a Mac.

```
Sub saveFATPMMMac()

 'Saves copy for access for everyone
 Dim FATPMetiPath As String
 Dim FATPMetiFolderPath As String


 FATPMetiFolderPath = "\Volumes\MFS1\Groups\METI\Quality Control\Function and Acceptance Test Documents\METIman\"
 'FATPMetiFolderPath = "C:\Users\gzapantis\Desktop\"
 FATPMetiPath = FATPMetiFolderPath & _
    Sheets("Failure Report").Range("FailReportSN").Text & " - FATP " & ".xlsm"

 ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FATPMetiPath

End Sub
```

Comment: OS X directory paths have different path seperators, windows uses `\ ` but mac uses `:` - you can account for both by using `Application.PathSeparator` instead. The rest of the code should run fine on OS X

Comment: @MacroMan the `:` separator is for posix paths. You should be able to use `/` in place of `\ ` for a mac path.

Comment: @Tom - I tried your suggestion and it saved it in the location of the original file still using the path and file name as the file name.

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap So it saved over the original file or as a duplicate?

Comment: @Tom - It saved in the folder where the original file was located instead of saving to the desired location.  It did not  save over the original, but saved  a separate copy with the Path and FolderPath values.

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap Have you tried `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs(FATPMetiPath), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` you'll need to remove the file extension from your path name or using `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(FATPMeitPath)`

Comment: @Tom - I was able to make it save, but it saved it as "FATPMetiPath" instead of pulling the value from the "FailReportSN" named range and it is not following the desired path either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.  It saves it with the correct file name and in the correct location.

```
Sub saveFATPMMMac()
'Saves copy for access for everyone
  Dim FATPMetiPath As String
  Dim FATPMetiFolderPath As String

 If Application.PathSeparator = ":" Then
    FATPMetiFolderPath = "Volumes:MFS1:Groups:METI:Quality Control:Function and Acceptance Test Documents:METIman:"
 Else
    FATPMetiFolderPath = "F:\Groups\METI\Quality Control\Function and Acceptance Test Documents\METIman\"
 End If

 FATPMetiPath = FATPMetiFolderPath & _
    Sheets("Failure Report").Range("FailReportSN").Text & " - FATP.xlsm"

 ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FATPMetiPath

End Sub
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.